# Making 2 outbound calls and join them into twilio conference using node js

Tags: node.js, twilio, call

Can any one please let me know how to join 2 outbound calls into conference

Answer (score 1):

Without further detail, we can't be too specific in the actual implementation however there will be a few steps:

1. You want to [dial in](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference) to create a conference.
2. Once created, you can reference this to [create a new participant](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource). This will dial the participant as an outbound call.
3. You can do this for the 2 parties in order to join them inside the same conference.